# How to select person with growing in height and weight?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as shown below. Person, Weight and Height.
**How i can select the person who has growing in his Weight and Height since 2001 to 2004(specific year range) ?** (John grow 20% each year on both parameters)

The expected query result is "John"

[image]

Comment: Ask the inverse question. Who didn't lose weight in any subsequent year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the people whose height and weight only increased from year to year:

```
select p.ID, p.Name
from (
    /* Tells you if the person did not gain weight since the previous year */
    select w.FK_Person, w.Year, case when w1.Weight > w.Weight or w1.Weight is null then 'gain' else 'not gain' end gain
    from Weight w
    left outer join Weight w1 on w.FK_Person = w1.FK_Person and w1.Year = w.year + 1    
) w
join (
    /* Tells you if the person did not gain height since the previous year */
    select w.FK_Person, w.Year, case when w1.Height > w.Height or w1.Height is null then 'gain' else 'not gain' end gain
    from Height w
    left outer join Height w1 on w.FK_Person = w1.FK_Person and w1.Year = w.year + 1    
) h on w.FK_Person = h.FK_Person and w.Year = h.Year
join Person p on p.ID = w.FK_Person
group by p.ID, p.Name
/* Filter out rows where the person had at least one year of not gaining */
having sum(case when w.gain = 'not gain' or h.gain = 'not gain' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query,

```
    SELECT P.NAME,W.YEAR,W.WEIGHT,H.HEIGHT FROM PERSON P,
    WEIGHT W,
    HEIGHT H,
    (SELECT MIN(WEIGHT) AS WEIGHT1 FROM WEIGHT WHERE YEAR = 2001) W1,
    (SELECT MIN(HEIGHT) AS HEIGHT1 FROM HEIGHT WHERE YEAR = 2001) H1
    WHERE 
    P.ID = W.FK_PERSON AND
    P.ID = H.FK_PERSON AND
    W.WEIGHT >= W1.WEIGHT1 AND
    H.HEIGHT >= H1.HEIGHT1
```

You can also use joins,

```
SELECT P.NAME,W.YEAR,W.WEIGHT,H.HEIGHT FROM PERSON P
INNER JOIN WEIGHT W
ON (P.ID = W.FK_PERSON)
WEIGHT W
INNER JOIN HEIGHT H
ON (P.ID = H.FK_PERSON)
HEIGHT H
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MIN(WEIGHT) AS WEIGHT1 FROM WEIGHT WHERE YEAR = 2001) W1
ON (P.ID = W1.FK_PERSON)
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MIN(HEIGHT) AS HEIGHT1 FROM HEIGHT WHERE YEAR = 2001) H1
ON (P.ID = H.FK_PERSON)
WHERE 
W.WEIGHT >= W1.WEIGHT1 AND
H.HEIGHT >= H1.HEIGHT1
```

Let me know in case you face any issues

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a bit of this:

```
select h1.fk_person, h1.height as oldHeight, h1.year as FirstYear, h2.height as NewHeight, h2.year as LastYear, ((h2.height-h1.height)/(h2.year-h1.year))/h1.height as pc_growth_py
from height h1
inner join height h2
  on h1.fk_person = h2.fk_person
where h1.year = (select max(year) from height x1 where x1.person = h1.person)
and h2.year = (select max(year) from height x2 where x2.person = h2.person)
```

And repeat for weight...

Then do this:

```
select Name
from Person p1
inner join <Height query> a1
on a1.fk_person = p1.id
inner join <weight query> a2
on a2.fk_person = p1.id
order by a1.pc_growth_py desc, a2.pc_growth_py desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example you can refer, it may help u.

```
   There are several ways... one is to just have two numeric columns, one for height, one for weight, then do the conversions (if necessary) at display time.  Another is to create a "height" table and a "weight" table, each with a primary key that is linked from another table.  Then you can store both English and metric values in these tables (along with any other meta info you want):

CREATE TABLE height (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    english     VARCHAR,
    inches      INT,
    cm          INT,
    hands       INT  // As in, the height of a horse
);

INSERT INTO height VALUES
    (1,'4 feet',           48, 122, 12),
    (2,'4 feet, 1 inch',   49, 124, 12),
    (3,'4 feet, 2 inches', 50, 127, 12),
    (3,'4 feet, 3 inches', 51, 130, 12),
    ....
```

You get the idea...

Then your users table will reference the **height** and **weight** tables--and possibly many other dimension tables--astrological sign, marital status, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uid         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    height      INT REFERENCES height(id),
    weight      INT references weight(id),
    sign        INT references sign(id),
    ...
);
```

Then to do a search for users between 4 and 5 feet:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN height ON users.height = height.id
WHERE height.inches >= 48 AND height.inches <= 60;
```

Several advantages to this method:

- You don't have to duplicate the "effort" (as if it were any real work) to do the conversion on display--just select the format you wish to display!
- It makes populating drop-down boxes in an HTML select super easy--just `SELECT english FROM height ORDER BY inches`, for instance.
- It makes your logic for various dimensions--including non-numerical ones (like astrological signs) obviously similar--you don't have special case code all over the place for each data type.
- It scales really well
- It makes it easy to add new representations of your data (for instance, to add the 'hands' column to the height table)